# OOB SharePoint permission level needed to break permissions at document level

Tags: sharepoint, permissions

What level of permissions will allow a user to break permission inheritance on a specific document and assign permissions to a subset of groups that have permission to the library that it resides in?

I was trying to create a customized permission level for the user that would need this ability, but it seems that SP OOB will not allow me to get this granular. I am trying to avoid giving customer FC b/c it seems like 'Design' does not allow them to break inheritance when I manage permissions on the specific file.

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so, yes, it is possible.

I ended up creating a customized permission that included the "Manage Permission" check box, and this seemed to work perfectly.

FYSA. I am using SP 2010